# Unexpected behaviour of grid items using justify-content property

Tags: css, css-grid

in the css-tricks complete-guide-to-css-grid it describes the justify-content property as follows:

> justify-content Sometimes the total size of your grid might be less
> than the size of its grid container. This could happen if all of your
> grid items are sized with non-flexible units like px. In this case you
> can set the alignment of the grid within the grid container. This
> property aligns the grid along the inline (row) axis (as opposed to
> align-content which aligns the grid along the block (column) axis).

Im trying to wrap my head around how this works. If I have a grid container with `width: 100%` and grid items with fixed width `width: 20px` and I set the grid container to `justify-items: start` the grid items will, as expected justify to the start. If however, I set the grid container to `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr) then the items no longer justify to the start? even though the items are sized with non-flexible units?

According to the css-tricks description I would have expected them to justify to the start of the row axis?

```css
.wrapper{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}

.grid{
display: grid;
grid-auto-flow: column;
justify-content: start;
align-content: start;
width: 100%;
padding: 1em;
background-color: powderblue;
}

.grid.explicit{
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.grid__item{
width: 20px;
padding:0.6em;
background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
Explicit columns
<pre>
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
</pre>
<div class="grid explicit">
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
</div>
Implicit columns
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: They are justified "start" **within** the grid cell width of `1fr`. Since you have set a specific width (albeit in `fr` units) the grid-columns are what you have set and then the grid-items are aligned as directed within those cells.

Comment: An Implicit grid cell has not defined width so they are just as wide as needed so the grid-item takes up the whole grid-cell. Thus no alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-align)

> If the grid’s outer edges do not correspond to the grid container’s content edges (for example, **if no columns are flex-sized**), the grid tracks are aligned within the content box according to the justify-content and align-content properties on the grid container.

So if any column is using `1fr`, `justify-content` is useless.

To use easy words: You grid container contain tracks (columns) that are sized either based on `grid-template-columns` or automatically. When using `1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr` You define 4 equal tracks taking all the available space. There is no free space so there is nothing to align because `justify-content` align the columns not the item inside them (that are equal to 20px).

When you don't define any size, the columns will get auto sized based on their content and in this case you will have tracks having their size equal to `20px` and inside them items also equal to `20px`. In this case, `justify-content` will align your columns.

Worth to note that the default alignment is stretch so in the second case if you omit the `justify-content`, your auto sized column will be stretched to fill all the space equally to have a similiar behavior as `1fr`.

to better understand, here is some illustration:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  justify-content: start;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: powderblue;
}

.grid__item {
  width: 20px;
  padding: 0.6em;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
4 equal columns
<div class="grid" style="grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr">
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
</div>
4 equal columns having 100px width (we have free space)
<div class="grid" style="grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px">
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
</div>

we align the items inside the columns
<div class="grid" style="grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;justify-items:center">
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
</div>
<div class="grid" style="grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;justify-items:end">
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
</div>
we move the columns to the end
<div class="grid" style="grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  justify-content: end;justify-items:end">
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
</div>
We make the column auto sized (nothing to align inside them)
<div class="grid" style="justify-items:center">
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
</div>
<div class="grid" style="justify-items:end">
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
  <div class="grid__item">item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant answer Temani Afif. Thank you for taking the time to explain.